# Display Rate module results via Panels

Tags: 7, panels, rating

So many of us know that the [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module does not smoothly integrate with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

I discovered out a way to get the voting widget to show using a custom content with the following PHP code:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ($node = node_load(arg(1)))) {
   print rate_embed($node, 'bias', RATE_FULL);
}
?>
```

Has anyone had any luck with doing something similar to display only the vote results (i.e. display total percent of that vote)?

I'm not a PHP wizard, but I think there is way by doing something like the following.

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ($node = node_load(arg(1)))) {
   print get_rate_resluts($node, 'bias', RATE_FULL);
}
?>
```

But end up getting either blank pages or some fatal database errors. Thoughts?

Update:
I think I figured out that I need to create a custom content to print the output after reading it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130017/how-to-print-output-in-drupal-hook-block#). Tried this:

```
$block['content'] = rate_get_results('bias', $nid, $widget_id) $output['rating'];
```

But it looks like it does not do anything which is better then seeing a blank page.

Comment: `rate_get_results('node', $nid, $widget_id)` found here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2483/12342 is what sparked the idea that this could be done.

Answer (score -1):

```
print rate_embed($node, 'NAME', RATE_FULL);
```

Replace *NAME* with the machine name of the widget; the view mode can be `RATE_FULL`, `RATE_COMPACT`, `RATE_DISABLED`, `RATE_CLOSED`, `RATE_COMPACT_DISABLED`.