# Sorting with Voting API

Tags: views, rating

I know a lot has been written on this issue already but I found no clear answer.

Here it is:

With the Voting API and another module such as Fivestars or Rate, how do you rank the results within results?

Let me give an example: With views, I can have a proper display of all the nodes that have received, say, 5 stars followed by all those that received 4 stars and so on. So the nodes are grouped properly.

But to rank the nodes within each group (i.e.: The 5 star node that have received the most number of votes being displayed first followed by the 5 star node that come in second position, etc. How does one set that in views?

At the present, I have no sorting within each star group so a node that has received one 5 star vote comes before one that has received three 5 stars, followed by one with that received two (1-3-2.)

My setting are:

Relationships: Content: Vote results -- Value type: No filtering -- Aggregation function: Average vote.
Sort criteria: Vote results: Value (desc.)

It looks like I need an additional sorting mechanism but i can't find it.

Any one has an answer for this? I am not a programmer but a site builder. :)

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I think I finally found the solution:

In addition to the settings above, I added a second relationships: Content: Vote results. It's the same relationship as before but instead of "Average vote" in the Aggregate function, I have "Number of votes." So as to avoid confusion, I also changed the identifier to: "Vote results (rank in group)"

So, I have two relationships, almost identical except for the Aggregate functions.

Then, in addition to the sort criteria described above, I added the same criteria again except that I chose the second relationship ("Vote results (rank in group)") instead. Order is also descending.

And that gave me the desired results: Nodes are properly ranked within the groups.

You can test this by enabling  **Text to display under the stars: Both user's and average vote** in the rating field.

:)

Hope that helps.